# Taking an infinite load to deploy in Hardhat js

Tags: javascript, api, ethereum, nft, hardhat

I'm trying to build an NFT site... I need to generate a contract and then deploy it, but when deploying it doesn't stop loading. I followed a youtube tutorial and the only thing I did differently was add a `gasPrice`. Can someone help me???

**Deploy.js:**

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
  console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);
  console.log("Account balance:", (await deployer.getBalance()).toString());
  const currentTimestampInSeconds = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
  const unlockTime = currentTimestampInSeconds + 60;

  const lockedAmount = hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("0.001");
  const ethAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther('0.01');

  const Lock = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Lock");
  const lock = await Lock.deploy();

  console.log(
    `Lock with ${ethers.utils.formatEther(lockedAmount)}ETH and unlock timestamp ${unlockTime} deployed to ${lock.address}`
  );
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

**hardhat.config.js:**

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
require('dotenv').config();

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.18",
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: process.env.REACT_APP_GOERLI_RPC_URL, 
      accounts: [process.env.REACT_APP_PRIVATE_KEY],
      gasPrice: 500000
    },
  },
  etherscan:{
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_ETHERSCAN_KEY
  }
};
```

**.env:**

```
REACT_APP_GOERLI_RPC_URL='' //my url to infura api key
REACT_APP_ETHERSCAN_KEY='' //my etherscan key
REACT_APP_PRIVATE_KEY='' //my private key
```

**Lock.sol (contract):**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';

contract Lock is ERC721, Ownable{
    uint256 public mintPrice;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    uint256 public maxSupply;
    uint256 public maxPerWallet;
    bool public isPublicMintEnabled;
    string internal baseTokenUri;
    address payable public withdrawWallet;

    mapping(address => uint256) public walletMints;

    constructor() payable ERC721('Lock', 'GB'){
        mintPrice = 0.001 ether;
        totalSupply = 0;
        maxSupply = 1000;
        maxPerWallet = 3;
    }

    function setIsPublicMintEnabled(bool isPublicMintEnabled_) external onlyOwner{
        isPublicMintEnabled = isPublicMintEnabled_;
    }

    function setBaseTokenUri(string calldata baseTokenUri_) external onlyOwner {
        baseTokenUri = baseTokenUri_;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId_) public view override returns (string memory){
        require(_exists(tokenId_),'Token does not exists');
        return string(abi.encodePacked(baseTokenUri, Strings.toString(tokenId_),".json"));
    }

    function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
        (bool success, ) = withdrawWallet.call{value: address(this).balance}('');
        require(success, 'withdraw failed');
    }

    function mint(uint256 quantity_) public payable {
        require(isPublicMintEnabled, 'minting not enabled');
        require(msg.value == quantity_ * mintPrice, 'wrong mint value');
        require(totalSupply + quantity_ <= maxSupply, 'sold out');
        require(walletMints[msg.sender] + quantity_ <= maxPerWallet, 'exceed max wallet');

        for(uint256 i=0; i<quantity_; i++){
            uint256 newTokenId = totalSupply + 1;
            totalSupply ++;
            _safeMint(msg.sender, newTokenId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but withdrawWallet is never set so youll never be able to collect